# How to implement Button insted of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a web form with question which will be answered by the user. These options are YES and NO. Firstly I was having radio button but they seems very old, so I tried to implement the button as a type in my input field. The problem is when I select and options from one question I cannot select other option from the other question

[image]

Is there is an another way to achieve this. Like in javascript. So that once the user select these option I can send that value to my PHP file.

My html code:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
           <label>XYZ QUESTION?</label>
            <input type="button" name="opt" value="YES">
            <input type="button" name="opt" value="NO">

            <label>XYZ QUESTION</label>
            <input type="button" name="opt1" value="YES">
            <input type="button" name="opt1" value="NO">

            <label>XYZ QUESTION?</label>
            <input type="button" name="opt2" value="YES">
            <input type="button" name="opt2" value="NO">
</form>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are probably the cleanest solution for passing back groups of one-choice-only data.  They're not a bad code practice at all.  There are tons of tricks to make them look more modern with CSS

Comment: @Doug can you suggest me some cool css tricks

Comment: `but they seems very old,` --> why old ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Now a days I have seen buttons instead of radio buttons on most of the websites

Comment: it doesn't mean they are old ... each website can rely on a ton of techniques .. if it achieve what you want and it's supported so it's fine .. your are not obliged to change simply because few website don't use them.

Comment: @samscoot, modern websites that have separate buttons often still make use of radio buttons and then apply styles to make the appearance of separate buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely ugly :) but it provides an example (one of the many possibilities out there) of how you can use CSS to create a look and feel for radio buttons; instead of accepting the browser's default display.

The big "trick" here is that an input's label can be clicked to trigger the action of the input element.  To create this link, make sure that the `<label for="">` is set to the **unique ID** of the input (radio) element.

The `+` in CSS finds the neighboring element that matches the rule. The same could have been achieved just by using classnames on the labels.

`:after` is a CSS psuedo-element -- pretty well supported these days (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

But like I said, this is one example.  A web search of something like "CSS style radio button" will pull up a ton of additional examples.

```css
input[type="radio"]{ 
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]+label{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"]+label:after{
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 3px green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input id="radioYes" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" class="yes" /><label for="radioYes"> YES </label>

<input id="radioNo" type="radio" name="test" value="no" class="no" /><label for="radioNo"> NO </label>
```